# Why are my div's not staying at minimum width?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a site for my school's robotics team and for some reason my div elements are not staying at their minimum width. Whenever I zoom out on the webpage they overlap and float to the top. How do I correct this?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_style.css">
<title>Team 3774: Team Bio</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Banner">
<img src="Banner.png" width="1350px" height="200">
</div>

<div class="navbar">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Team Bio">Team Bio</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Our Robot">Our Robot</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Our Coach">Our Coach</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Outreach">Outreach</a></li>
  <li><a class="li_nav" href="/Youtube">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="Team_Bio">
 <div class="example">
  <h2>Team Bio</h2>
   <h1>Example</h1>
    <ul>
     <li class="li_info">class</li>
     <li class="li_info">Role</li>
     <li class="li_info">Career Interests</li>
     <li class="li_info">Other Clubs and Sports</li>
    </ul>
 </div>

<div class="Abanoub_Boules">
    <div class="info_AB">
        <h1>Abanoub Boules</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Captian, Coder, Documenter</li> 
        <li class="li_info">CEO of a Biology Firm</li>
        <li class="li_info">Coptic Society</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        <li class="li_info">President of Stem Clubs</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="picture_AB">
    <img src="Abanoub.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
   </div>
  </div>



<div class="Andre_Bernardo">
    <div class="info_ABe">
        <h1>Andre Bernardo</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, 3D modeling</li>
        <li class="li_info">Computer Science</li>
        <li class="li_info">Tennis</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_ABe">
        <img src="Andre.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
   </div>


<div class="Leo_Scarano">
    <div class="info_LS">
        <h1>Leo Scarano</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, Coder</li>
        <li class="li_info">Computer Science</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_LS">
        <img src="Leo.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Mina_Hanna">
    <div class="info_MH">   
        <h1>Mina Hanna</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, Coder</li>
        <li class="li_info">Pharmaceutics</li>
        <li class="li_info">Coptic Society</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_MH">
        <img src="Mina.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Kenneth_Rebbecke">
    <div class="info_KR">   
        <h1>Kenneth Rebbecke</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, Documenter</li>
        <li class="li_info">Structual Engineering</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_KR">
        <img src="Kenny.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Kristen_Kaldas">
    <div class="info_KK">
        <h1>Kristen Kaldas</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Coder, Bookkeeper</li>
        <li class="li_info">Biomedical Engineering</li>
        <li class="li_info">Science Seminar</li>
        <li class="li_info">Science Club</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_KK">
        <img src="Kristen.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Melanie_Aguilar">
    <div class="info_MA">
        <h1>Melanie Agular</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Secratary, Mascot</li>
        <li class="li_info">Party Planner</li>
        <li class="li_info">Yearbook</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_MA">
        <img src="Melanie.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div> 

 <div class="Anish_Patel">
    <div class="info_AP">
        <h1>Anish Patel</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Junior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, 3d modeling</li>
        <li class="li_info">Mechanical Engineer</li>
        <li class="li_info">Science Club</li>
        <li class="li_info">Junior Classical League</li>
        <li class="li_info">Certamn</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_AP">
        <img src="Anish.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Furhan_Ashraf">
    <div class="info_FA">   
        <h1>Furhan Ashraf</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Junior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Financial Advisor, Engineer</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineering/Undecided</li>
        <li class="li_info">Science Club</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_FA">
        <img src="Furhan.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Andrew_W">
    <div class="info_AW">
        <h1>Andrew Wojtkowski</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, 3d Modeling</li>
        <li class="li_info">Aerospace Engineer</li>
        <li class="li_info">Varsity Hockey</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_AW">
        <img src="Andrew.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="Bryan_F">
    <div class="info_BF">
        <h1>Bryan Ferreira</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="li_info">Senior</li>
        <li class="li_info">Engineer, Documenter</li>
        <li class="li_info">Computer Engineer/Civil Engineer</li>
        <li class="li_info">Guitar</li>
        <li class="li_info">Technology Student Association</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="picture_BF">
        <img src="Bryan.jpg" width="350px" height="350px">
    </div>
</div>



 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.li_nav
{
float: left;
display:inline-block;
}

.nav 
{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden; 
min-width: 1350PX;  
}

a:link, a:visited 
{
display:inline-block;
width: 182.7px;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
padding-left: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #990000;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active 
{
background-color: #B20000;
}

.Team_Bio
{
min-width: 1350px;
}

 h2 
{
 font-size: 60px;
}

 .example 
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

 .Abanoub_Boules 
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

    .info_AB
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 500px;
    }

    .picture_AB
    {
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
    height: 420px;
    }


 .Andre_Bernardo 
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

    .info_ABe
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 500px;
    }

    .picture_ABe
    {
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
    height: 425px;
    }
}

 .Leo_Scarano 
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

    .info_LS
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 400px;
    }

    .picture_LS
    {
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
    height: 400px;
    }

 .Mina_Hanna 
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

    .info_MH
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 425px;
    }

    .picture_MH
    {
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
    height: 425px;
    }

 .Kenneth_Rebbecke 
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

    .info_KR
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 400px;
    }

    .picture_KR
    {
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
    height: 400px;
    }

 .Kristen_Kaldas 
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

    .info_KK
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 425px;
    }

    .picture_KK
    {
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
    height: 425px;
    }

 .Melanie_Aguilar 
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

    .info_MA
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 400px;
    }

    .picture_MA
    {
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
    height: 400px;
    }

 .Anish_Patel
{
  float: left;
  min-width: 1350px;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

    .info_AP
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 425px;
    }

    .picture_AP
    {
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
    height: 425px;
    }

 .Furhan_Ashraf
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350px;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

    .info_FA
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 425px;
    }

    .picture_FA
    {
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
    height: 425px;
    }

 .Andrew_W 
{
  float: left;
  width: 1350;
  height: 425px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

    .info_AW
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 425px;
    }

    .picture_AW
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 425px;
    }

.Bryan_F
{
float: left;
width: 1350px;
height: 400px;
}

    .info_BF
    {
    float: left;
    width: 675px;
    height: 400px;
    }

    .picture_BF
    {
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
    height: 400px;
    }

 .li_info
{
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

The site is robotichive3774.com if you want to take a look at it and see what I mean. It is under the team bio page.

Comment: Why are you repeating the same CSS over and over? If you want two different classes to have the same style, you can use both in the same selector by separating them with a comma: `.Furhan_Ashraf, .Andrew_W, ... { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a div at the beginning like

```
<div id="page">
```

and add the following to your css

```
#page{
width:1000px;
margin:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmksn5qv/